# Add "%" suffix in ng-options with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-options

I want to include **%** symbol in the options of an array using `ng-options`.

Here is the code:

```
$scope.load_percentages = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50];

<select ng-model="loaddata.loadPercent" ng-options="loadpercentnumber as {loadpercentnumber + '%' +} for loadpercentnumber in load_percentages track by loadpercentnumber"> 
</select>
```

But getting error like not correct way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use bracets:

```
ng-options="loadpercentnumber as loadpercentnumber + '%' for loadpercentnumber in load_percentages track by loadpercentnumber"
```

## [JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/k4que0jL/1/)

Comment: my mistake :( I tried with + % + but got error, as you suggested removed right side + and its working

Comment: @Kranthi Glad I helped. Could you accept the answer if it solved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You almost got it right.
Use:

```
<select ng-model="loaddata.loadPercent" name="loadPercent" ng-options="o as o+'%' for o in load_percentages"> 
</select>
```

See [this JSFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/30348/).

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead of the actual `%` sign: `&#37;`